# Condition based counter in select loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on movie database in php. I have a large form in which the user can add cast and crew names into a table called tbl_cast_person and tbl_crew_person. When a duplicate name is met and discovered by UNIQUE keyword in a table I store theese duplicate values in a single table called tbl_dup_actor. I then try to update this tbl_dup_actor-table with a counter so the output should look like below

George Henry-2
George Henry-3
George Henry-4
Matthew Fox-2
Matthew Fox-3
Matthew Fox-4

I can only get it to work so it looks like the output below this line

George Henry-2
George Henry-3
George Henry-4
Matthew Fox-5
Matthew Fox-6
Matthew Fox-7

My loop for updating the the table tbl_dup_actor looks at the moment like this

```
while ($query = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                
    $counter++;
                
    $id = $query["id"];
    $name=$query["person_name"];                                                            
    $person = $name . '-' . $counter;
                                                                        
    $update_stmt->bindValue(":person_name",
    $person,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    
    $update_stmt->bindValue(":number",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

  }

  $update_stmt->execute();
                            
}
```

My update sql looks like this

```
UPDATE tbl_dup_actor SET person_name = :person_name WHERE id = :number
```

My question is how can I make the counter reset back to 2 each time when a new value is met in the select loop in which I do the updating ? I hope I have described my problem well to some extent anyway. Many Thanks for viewing my post. I know I am a little unclear about one or two things but I have tried my best to be clear here.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a tip. How about you, when perform insert check for duplicates if find someone perform the single update task. Your database will thanks you, and the operation will be more easy to modify and add more rules. With your approach you perform a very heavy task where you really need just one real result. So performing it into insert should be a great bet

Answer (score -1):

you can do this directly in MySQL, but it relies on that he table has a unique identifier. In the example it is id, but can be every other UNIQUE column

Update To extend my answer:

the Query

`SELECT     u1.`name`, CONCAT(u1.`name `..`

Showas in the result what the `CONCAT` in combination with `ROW_NUMBER` makes. the result is shown in the column newname in the result set below

So to update the table, you need to run an `UPDATE` that  is a bit tricky so i suppluied it as well.

## Caution

**Before** you `UPDATE` any table in a production test it extensively in an test enviroment.

And even **before udpating** your live tables, **first make a complete Backup** and test if ou can restore it to the original state if something happens.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE usermeta
>     (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `name` varchar(100)
>     ,
>      PRIMARY KEY (id))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO usermeta
>     (`name`)
> VALUES
>     ('George Henry'),
>     ('George Henry'),
>     ('George Henry'),
>     ('Matthew Fox'),
>     ('Matthew Fox'),
>     ('Matthew Fox'),
>     ('Aston Martin')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> u1.`name`, CONCAT(u1.`name`,'-',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`) + 1) newname
> FROM 
> usermeta u1 JOIN (SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) FROM usermeta GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
> ON u1.`name` = u2.`name`
> ```
>
> ```
> name         | newname       
> :----------- | :-------------
> George Henry | George Henry-2
> George Henry | George Henry-3
> George Henry | George Henry-4
> Matthew Fox  | Matthew Fox-2 
> Matthew Fox  | Matthew Fox-3 
> Matthew Fox  | Matthew Fox-4
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE usermeta u1,
> (SELECT
> u1.`id`, CONCAT(u1.`name`,'-',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`) + 1) newname
> FROM 
> usermeta u1 JOIN (SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) FROM usermeta GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
> ON u1.`name` = u2.`name` ) u3
> SET u1.`name` = u3.`newname`
> WHERE u1.`id` = u3.`id`
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM usermeta
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name          
> -: | :-------------
>  1 | George Henry-2
>  2 | George Henry-3
>  3 | George Henry-4
>  4 | Matthew Fox-2 
>  5 | Matthew Fox-3 
>  6 | Matthew Fox-4 
>  7 | Aston Martin
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=729860c8a2d4476a98bf3b3b8dc4c314)*

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION `toRoman`(inArabic int unsigned) RETURNS varchar(15) CHARSET latin1 DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE numeral CHAR(7) DEFAULT 'IVXLCDM';
>
>     DECLARE stringInUse CHAR(3);
>     DECLARE position tinyint DEFAULT 1;
>     DECLARE currentDigit tinyint;
>
>     DECLARE returnValue VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT '';
>
>     IF(inArabic > 3999) THEN RETURN 'overflow'; END IF;
>     IF(inArabic = 0) THEN RETURN 'N'; END IF;
>
>     WHILE position <= CEIL(LOG10(inArabic + .1)) DO
>         SET currentDigit := MOD(FLOOR(inArabic / POW(10, position - 1)), 10);
>
>         SET returnValue := CONCAT(
>             CASE currentDigit
>                 WHEN 4 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(numeral, position * 2 - 1, 1), SUBSTRING(numeral, position * 2, 1))
>                 WHEN 9 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(numeral, position * 2 - 1, 1), SUBSTRING(numeral, position * 2 + 1, 1))
>                 ELSE CONCAT(
>                     REPEAT(SUBSTRING(numeral, position * 2, 1), currentDigit >= 5),
>                     REPEAT(SUBSTRING(numeral, position * 2 - 1, 1), MOD(currentDigit, 5))
>                 )
>             END,
>             returnValue);
>
>         SET position := position + 1;
>     END WHILE;
>     RETURN returnValue;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> u1.`name`, CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`) = 1 THEN u1.`name` ELSE 
> CONCAT(u1.`name`,'-',toRoman(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`) + 1)) END newname
> FROM 
> usermeta u1 JOIN (SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) FROM usermeta GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
> ON u1.`name` = u2.`name`
> ```
>
> ```
> name         | newname         
> :----------- | :---------------
> George Henry | George Henry    
> George Henry | George Henry-III
> George Henry | George Henry-IV 
> Matthew Fox  | Matthew Fox     
> Matthew Fox  | Matthew Fox-III 
> Matthew Fox  | Matthew Fox-IV
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE usermeta u1,
> (SELECT
> u1.`id`
> , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`) = 1 THEN u1.`name` ELSE 
> CONCAT(u1.`name`,'-',toRoman(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`) + 1)) END newname
> FROM 
> usermeta u1 JOIN (SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) FROM usermeta GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
> ON u1.`name` = u2.`name` ) u3
> SET u1.`name` = u3.`newname`
> WHERE u1.`id` = u3.`id`
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM usermeta
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name            
> -: | :---------------
>  1 | George Henry    
>  2 | George Henry-III
>  3 | George Henry-IV 
>  4 | Matthew Fox     
>  5 | Matthew Fox-III 
>  6 | Matthew Fox-IV  
>  7 | Aston Martin
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b042efadebe0383531c96e6262ea363)*

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, for your kind reply! My SQL-knowledge are very limited. I'm not that familiar with the partition part. Also I am not sure what the word newname does. Many questions arise, sorry for that. I am trying to translate your fine sql-code into a php-method, but it seems almost impossible for me to manage that.

Comment: the second query shows how it works, as you can see all duplicate get a number qattacjed to them incrementing the number, this coumn is called newname as it is fitting. T%he second query show that iot works also with updating the zjr zsblr, there i join the second quer to replace the name column with the created newname. you such make a backup for our database and run the update query. you also should use the provided fiddle to add your own names  and try it

Comment: Sir, @nbk, your sql-code is really something that I have wanted to write myself. But It is so difficult to implement this into php. In php we use prepared statement when it comes to pdo. Can you show me an example of how your sql-code would like using  prepared statements ? I don't know how to update the table usermeta using prepared statements. I am a little confused so I am really sorry for that and I am a slow learner.

Comment: in php you make a string like `$mysql = "code here"`and execute it and run it, but it would be better to run it directly in the server per phpmyadmin, , there you can make te backup that must be done earlier

Comment: you see the joing subquery, it has at the end a having Count > 1, this reoves allnames that are already unique, so there is no need to add a number

Comment: mysql has no suich function but you can write your own

Comment: thank you so much for your kind replies and examples. I really need to implement theese in my code but I try to add some modification to them. I try to get them all numbered when the user adds a duplicate name. Can you in sql start a counter loop that updates each entry with a unique number and start over on term that the entry is unique from the previous ones ? I am reading on this very much. I am working on a movie database in imdb-style.

Comment: Please help, I am stuck and on a limited schedule.  I must have all of the duplicates numbered.  Good news is I am close now. Can someone help me out here? Kind Regards, Ingmar!

Comment: I can't get this to work in phpmyadmin the counter starts over after the duplicate names untill a new value is met. I wonder why?

Comment: tha is what row_number with partitioninhg does, for every new partition aka name it start by 1 and that was what you wanted as result in your question. read up on the window functions. new names you can capturte in an BEFORE INSERT Trigger, look up if the name exists, if yes get the last number with https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp and increse it  and add it as romann numerals add the name

Comment: I understand how partitioning works now. But I can't get your fine examples to work in phpmyadmin. Evertime I reload phpmyadmin the counter starts from 1 again after each group of duplicate names. That's weird.

Answer (score -1):

First off, I changed the database design. I normalised your tables as follows:

- persons (id, firstname, lastname)
- cast (id, persons.id)
- crew (id, persons.id)

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL, lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE cast (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, person INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `fk_cast_person_id` FOREIGN KEY (person) REFERENCES persons (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE crew (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, person INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `fk_crew_person_id` FOREIGN KEY (person) REFERENCES persons (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Anton', 'Arabella'), ('Anton', 'Arabella'), ('Anton', 'Arabella'), ('Bruno', 'Banane'), ('Caroline', 'Champagner'), ('Bruno', 'Banane'), ('Bruno', 'Banane'), ('Bruno', 'Banane');

INSERT INTO cast (person) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (7), (8);
INSERT INTO crew (person) VALUES (4), (5), (6);
```

Also, I have my SQL query handle the counters for the duplicate entries.

```sql
-- Replace the JOIN operand as needed

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.firstname, p.lastname ORDER BY p.firstname ASC, p.lastname ASC) id, p.firstname, p.lastname
  FROM persons p
  JOIN (SELECT firstname, lastname -- get the duplicate names
          FROM persons
          JOIN cast ON persons.id = cast.person
      GROUP BY firstname, lastname
        HAVING COUNT(firstname) > 1) duplicates ON p.firstname = duplicates.firstname AND p.lastname = duplicates.lastname
   JOIN cast ON p.id = cast.person;
```

As you can see, my approach is quite different. The output also includes the very first pair of (firstname, lastname) indicated by the id = 1.

Sample output:

```sql
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Anton     | Arabella |
|  2 | Anton     | Arabella |
|  3 | Anton     | Arabella |
|  1 | Bruno     | Banane   |
|  2 | Bruno     | Banane   |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Cheers